# Map backtick key to Esc and tilde with xkb Ubuntu 18.04 even on applications like chrome, slack etc

Tags: xkb, remapping

I'm trying to map backtick key to Esc while shift-backtick as tilde unchanged.

Here's what I've done.

`key <TLDE> { [Escape, asciitilde] };  // in X11/xkb/symbols/us`

It works all fine in terminal, but in application like chrome or slack,

shift-backtick is recognized as shift Esc. I want it to print tilde(~).

When backtick pressed without shift, it functions okay as Esc even on apps.

Here's my environment. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
>> setxkbmap -query -verbose 10

Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,kr
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+kr:2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,kr
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I'm using fcitx as Input Method Framework.

Any help would be much appreciated.